# For every $a$ in $\mathbb N^+$, prove that there exist a natural number $b$ such that $b++=a$.

Tags: proof-writing, peano-axioms

The question is listed above. The question is that whether$\forall a\in \mathbb{N^+}, \exists b\in \mathbb{N} \,,s.t.a=b++$ is right.

My question is, in my proof, I’ve tried to use the mathematical induction, but as I assume that if the number $n$ satisfies the situation, the element $n++$ could easily make sense, so I’m wondering whether the mathematical induction could make sense.

The question is quite trivial but I’m really caught in trouble. Hoping for help.

Comment: Does "$a=b++$" mean "$a=b+1$"?

Comment: What is $b++$? $\hspace{1pt}$

Comment: @ElliotG Some author uses $n++$ to denote the [successor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function) of $n$. (eg. Terence Tao's Analysis I)

Comment: @Dave yep, it means, but it should be proved by some lemmas

Comment: maybe you should change $b++$ with $S(b)$ to denote the successor and add a note that it means "successor of b"

Comment: When it comes to obvious truths like this, the question always becomes: exactly what axioms are you supposed to work with?